# Display .csv in excel correctly

Tags: python, excel, csv, bexio

I have written a python script that fetches the data via API and writes it to a CSV. But now I have the problem that when I open the CSV in an Excel, everything is displayed in one column. I don't know what exactly I'm doing wrong. I have specified ***"sep=";"*** ( or ***"sep=","***) , yet the same result is returned.

[image: notebad]
[image: excel]

This is what my code looks like.

```
url = "https://api.bexio.com/2.0/article"
r = requests.get('https://api.bexio.com/2.0/article')
headers = {
    'Accept': "application/json",
    'Content-Type': "application/json",
    'Authorization': "",
}

# Grab Dataframes from Bexio-API and export to CSV
response = requests.request("GET", url, headers=headers)
dic = response.json()
df = pd.DataFrame(dic)
column_map = {'intern_code': 'ProviderKey', 'stock_available_nr': 'QuantityOnStock',}
df.columns = df.columns.map(lambda x: column_map.get(x, x))
df = df[column_map.values()]
df = df[df['ProviderKey'].str.contains('MNM')]
df.to_csv('StockData.csv', index=False, sep=";")

# Send Data to FTP
ftp = FTP("")
ftp.login("","")
Output_Directory = ""
File2Send=""
ftp.cwd(Output_Directory)
with open(File2Send, "rb") as f:
    ftp.storbinary('STOR ' + os.path.basename(File2Send), f)
```

Does anyone here have any idea what I am doing wrong?

Thanks a lot!

Update: added screenshot from csv in vi
[image: vi]

Comment: You have given the code, and this is nice. But you should also show the content of the CSV file **as text** (I mean open it with notepad, vi, emacs, notepad++ or any other text editor and show what you get), at least the first rows.

Comment: You are right, of course. I have added these.

Comment: I'm not a Python guy, but the examples I see from a quick Google have the separator specified within single-quotes, where yours are double. No idea if that would make a difference though?

Comment: I wanted the csv file as **text** to be able to see the delimiter and the presence of quotes. An image in a spreasheet (yeah, spread shit) is useless for that.

Comment: I added a screenshot from the csv file as text in vi :)

Comment: can you send code for to_csv() function you used to write the data to file.

Comment: you should load it into excel with a specified delimiter. Go to data tab and there click import and from the dialog select 'delimited' and press next. Then select the type of delimiter which is comma in your case and see if the problem is solved!

Comment: **as text** is suggested for your data so that we can copy/paste the data into a file and test with it. This is not possible if you have provided a screenshot image. As a screenshot you are asking us to manually type it in.

Comment: Hello all. First of all, thank you very much for your answers! I don't know why, but I programmed sep=";" again and adjusted the timezone of the server and then it finally worked. No idea why...